# Missing Variables in JSONArray with Volley in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I'm requesting some json data from database with 3 variable. This is the response

`[{"id":"a5","catname":"a","full":"yes"},{"id":"a4","catname":"a","full":"no"},{"id":"a3","catname":"a","full":"yes"}]`

But Volley response doesn't catch a variable names 'full'

Below is my Code

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, getString(R.string.latest_url), new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(jresponse.has("full")) {
                        arrayList.add(new Album(jresponse.getString("id"), jresponse.getString("catname"), jresponse.getString("full")));
                    }else{
                        arrayList.add(new Album(jresponse.getString("id"), jresponse.getString("catname"), ""));
                    }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
                try {
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                    recycleradapter = new recyclerGridAdapter(getContext(), arrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return params;
        }
    };
```

I'm using PHP script to get data in Array

`array_push($response,array("id"=>$row["id"],"catname"=>$row["catname"],"full"=>$row["full"]));`

Is there something wrong? Is there anything missing?

Comment: ensure you are getting **proper response** using `postman` or any other tools, also what are your `post` contents

Comment: I'm not passing anything in POST

Comment: Yes I'm getting same response that includes 3 variables `'id','catname','full'` using `postman`

Comment: It looks like there is problem in POST method `Request.Method.POST` method in Volley library. Problem solved by changing it to GET method `Request.Method.GET`. But I was getting proper response in `postman` using POST method.

Comment: There is one problem I'm having, I'm getting null values in Volley Response. I'm not sure what's wrong. Can you please suggest me something?

Comment: which value is returning `null`

Comment: value of `full` is always null in VolleyResponse

Comment: since you have added `if(jresponse.has("full")) {` if the `full` key is not present in response you are saving `full` as `""` in your model, if this is not the case add a log for your response string and paste it here

Comment: No. The condition is true for `jresponse.has("full")` and I've debugged app and It executes line under if statement. Here is the response:

    [{"id":"a5","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a4","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a3","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a2","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a1","catname":"a","full":""}]

Comment: And response in `postman`:
[{"id":"a5","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a4","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a3","catname":"a","full":""},{"id":"a2","catname":"a","full":"yesthereis"},{"id":"a1","catname":"a","full":"yesthereis"}]

Comment: Turns out it was Volley Cache that was causing this problem. Volley was using cache of previous data. Any new or modified data wasn't reflecting in volley's response. I used `jsonArrayRequest.setShouldCache(false);` so that Volley won't use any cache. Thanks for your cordination